# How can I enable permissions on the partner object for the api user?

Tags: api, permissions, partner

I'm attempting to do a create on a partner object via the api but am running across the following error - 'INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Partner' is not supported.'. It would appear that the API user does not have permissions on this object. Is this the case, and if so, how do I set permissions on this object? I can't find any helpful documentation regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to docs :

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_partner.htm

> You must have the “View All Data” permission to access this object via
>   the API.

Go to the user's profile Search for Administrative privileges and set **view All Data** permission.

[image]